# Is there a way to limit private channels requests to those the user has access to?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm working with the Graph to retrieve users Teams and Channels, but have come across an issue with making calls to the /v1.0/teams/[team-id]/channels endpoint. It lists out all channels in the team, including private channels the user doesn't have access to. We have to make an extra call to the specific channel to see if the user has access, which in our case means we have to batch potentially hundreds of calls and that has the potential to block rendering of our add-in.

In the following example, this user has access to a team called 'Test Team with public sharing' and has access to the 'General' and 'Canal partage' channels. There's a private channel 'Private channel' the user isn't a part of, and a shared channel that we were using for testing.
You can see the private channel is in the response from /[team-id]/channels:
[image: Graph explorer response]
But the channel doesn't appear in the Teams client:

[image: Teams client without private channel]

Is there a way to filter out channels the user doesn't have access to? Is this something I can request? At best it has the potential to significantly impact performance of our add-in, at worst it could open users up to security issues. Consider a private channel created to discuss the future of an employee, or a group of dissatisfied employees creates a 'Our boss is mean' private channel and excludes their boss. The channel won't show in the Teams client, but has the potential to show in any other add-in or application that uses the Graph API.

In our add-in we're using this call to exclude shared channels for the moment:

/channels?& $select=id,displayName,membershipType,webUrl$filter=membershipType eq 'private' or membershipType eq 'standard'

Ideally the Graph would exclude channels the user doesn't have access to, next best thing would be to have a property on the channel to identify the user doesn't have permissions. Maybe a permissions mask or something like that.

Comment: As an update, I've done some testing and it seems like if the user is a Teams Administrator they have access to these channels via the Graph calls. Regular users see this error response:
`{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "UnknownError",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "[DATE]",
            "request-id": "[GUID]",
            "client-request-id": "[GUID]"
        }
    }
}`